# Some questions relating to writing project number

Tags: line-breaking, punctuation, ieeetran

I'm writing acknowledgement for a paper and have some questions that I need some help. 
The acknowledgement is something like below with some modification to hide the real name.

> This   research   was   supported  by  the  XXX(Ministry  of  Science
> and  Technology),  under  the  YYY(Technology  Research  Center)    support          program(No.2022-2-221155.01) supervised    by    the
> ZZZ(Institute    for    Information    &    Technology).

Question:

1. What type of dash that I should use in `2022-2-221155`?
2. In my document, `No.2022-2-221155.01` is breaked to a new line (the `221155.01` moves to a new line). Is this normal for a project number like that? How would you write that?

Comment: It looks normal. Only the editor can decide if they accept it or not

Comment: I would use some like `\mbox{No.\,2022--2--221155.01}` but most probably you should not concern about this.